# Jquery drop down menu is jumping

Tags: jquery

when i am mouse over on Tab2 drop down menu is jumping... plz help me..

this is the html to see http://jsfiddle.net/ram8022/p4gLj/

Answer (score 0):

You want `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` instead

Answer (score 0):

try hover , this doesn't flicker

```
$("div").hover(
  function () {
    //mouseover
  }, 
  function () {
//mouseout
  }
);
```

i tested in jsfiddle this is working fine

```
$("#testtwo").hover(
  function () {
         $(".dropdown").slideDown("normal");
  }, 
  function () {
         $(".dropdown").slideUp("normal");
  }
);
```

Comment: wait , i will try in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

try this please

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
     $("div.dropMain > ul > li").mouseenter(function()
         {
             $('ul', this).slideDown("normal");
         }
     );
     $("div.dropMain > ul > li").mouseleave(function()
         {
             $('ul', this).slideUp("normal");
         }
     );
  }
 );
```

Comment: one issue if i am doing mouse over on it two three time those many time animation is running...

Comment: just add `$('ul', this).stop()` before the slideUp and Down